# Recursive Push Pop Postfix Calculator not properly doing operations, simply takes the last number as the result

Tags: c++, recursion

I have a recursive push pop postfix calculator I'm supposed to do and where I'm confused on is where I'm going wrong. The only interesting thing about this push pop I'm doing for my assignment is that **pop() does not return the value**, but simply a true/false as to whether or not it was able to complete the operation. Peek is used to retrieve the top number. The array I'm using is storing char's, program starts off by simply stating "Please enter expression: " and it's supposed to take one string. I have it set up so that it ignore's spaces and only accepts numbers and the +-*/ signs.

```
int num = 0
int operate(int num)
{
    while(!stack.isEmpty()){
        if(isdigit(stack.peek()))
        {
            num = (int) stack.peek() - '0';
            stack.pop();
            return num;
        }
        else if(stack.peek() == '+')
        {
            stack.pop();
            return num + operate(num);
        }
        else if(stack.peek() == '-')
        {
            stack.pop();
            return num - operate(num);
        }
        else if(stack.peek() == '/')
        {
            stack.pop();
            return num / operate(num);
        }
        else if(stack.peek() == '*')
        {
            stack.pop();
            return num * operate(num);
        }
    }

    return num;
}
```

What's seems to be the problem is that it's not adding anything, but merely returning the first number. Using flags it's able to call the correct amount of times, but simply does not add, subtract, divide, or multiply correctly.

The output looks like this

```
Enter postfix expression: 1 2 +
Pushing 1
Pushing 2
Pushing +
Result: 2
Done? Yes/No: No
Enter postfix expression: 2 2 +
Pushing 2
Pushing 2
Pushing +
Result: 2
Done? Yes/No: No
Enter postfix expression: 1 1 -
Pushing 1
Pushing 1
Pushing -
Result: -1
Done? Yes/No: No
Enter postfix expression: 2 2 *
Pushing 2
Pushing 2
Pushing *
Result: 2
```

I know my issue is with my line of thinking, but as per my textbook it should be correct.

Comment: As per what textbook?

Answer (score 1):

Binary operators have *two* operands. For example, on `+` you need to pop two values, add them, and push the result. Note that for subtraction and division the operands aren't pushed in the correct order: you have to swap them.

'Pushing +' is meaningless.

You don't need recursion. You already have a stack, and you're even misusing that by pushing all the input into it. The stack is for intermediate and final *results*. Postfix is a linear notation that can be executed with nothing more complex than a stack for intermediate results, but there is no point in *starting* with a stack. The input is just a linear list of operands and operators.

Answer (score 0):

Say you are calling it with

```
return operate(num);
```

and you have a stack of:
2
2
+

The first time would pop + out of the stack.

```
else if(stack.peek() == '+')
{
    stack.pop();
    return 0 + operate(0); // and do this
}
```

The second time would pop 2 out of the stack and do this,

```
if(isdigit(stack.peek()))
{
    num = (int) stack.peek() - '0'; // num = 2
    stack.pop();  // 2 is popped
    return num;  // return 2
}
```

And walla, you have 2 as your result.

Comment: Thank you for pointing that out. I figured it out per having the return finding a **second** number

Answer (score -1):

I was able to figure out my answer, I was finding the first number in the operational statements, but not any other numbers.

The correct code is just slightly different

```
int operate(int num)
{
    while(!stack.isEmpty()){
        if(isdigit(stack.peek()))
        {
            num = (int) stack.peek() - '0';
            stack.pop();
            return num;
        }
        else if(stack.peek() == '+')
        {
            stack.pop();
            return operate(num) + operate(num);
        }
        else if(stack.peek()== '-')
        {
            stack.pop();
            return operate(num) - operate(num);
        }
        else if(stack.peek() == '/')
        {
            stack.pop();
            return operate(num) / operate(num);
        }
        else if(stack.peek() == '*')
        {
            stack.pop();
            return operate(num) * operate(num);
        }
    }

    return num;
}
```

Comment: You are totally barking up the wrong tree with this approach.